# Apache Ignite : We are not getting results even for 200 records

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

We have not been able to fetch records from Ignite for even 200 records:

```
 [reqId=10, req=JdbcQueryExecuteRequest [schemaName=PUBLIC, pageSize=1024, maxRows=200, sqlQry=SELECT sum(recordId) FROM PUBLIC.SPECTRAMD_CONDITION
ORDER BY recordId, args=Object[]*
```

We have 34 million records in single ignite table (`PUBLIC.SPECTRAMD_CONDITION`), running on single node on a machine, but are only retrieving 200 rows from same, but still no results are being retrieved, with query keeping on executing.

We have also enabled the following property `"lazy:true;collocated=true"`.

Can you please help us to find what is the issue, and how to improve the performance?

This is our ignite configuration in XML:

```xml
<property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
          <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
              <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                  <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
      <property name="name" value="default_data_region"/>
      <property name="initialSize" value="#{5L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
              </bean>
          </property>
  <property name="pageSize" value="#{8 * 1024}"/>

      </bean>
    </property>

<property name="cacheConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
        <property name="name" value="myCache"/>
        <property name="sqlOnheapCacheEnabled" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Comment: We'd need to see more of the exception. A single node isn't how to get the best performance out of a _distributed_ database, of course.

Comment: We are trying to fetch result for only 200 records from the ignite, but query keeps on executing.  What we need to do to improve the performance?

Comment: The query you show returns a single row, but needs to read 34mm records to get the answer.

Comment: We are only fetching sum for 200 records, and still we don't get the answer. In the query shared above, maxRows set is 200. Are we missing any settings?

Comment: `maxRows` means _return_ no more than 200 rows. You could do something like `select sum(recordId) from (SELECT recordId FROM PUBLIC.SPECTRAMD_CONDITION limit 200)`

Comment: The query is internally created by the tibco tool, which is using ignite-core jar. Even if we do select count(*) from table, we don't get result back. Is any configuration missed? With query that you posted has been working fine, but we don't have control on query creation as its internal from tibco Jasper and ignite core.

Comment: I guess you need to take it up with Tibco. Summing an ID column doesn't seem like a sensible thing to do? More heap space would probably heap. More nodes (doubling the number of nodes, halves the amount of data each machine has to work with). _Possibly_ an index on the recordID column (if it's not the primary key).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your client is closing query cursor too soon.

Also, maybe you forget to close query cursor once you read all that you have wanted.

Comment: Even if we try to use dbeaver tool to get records, we don't get the result. Is any configuration missed while starting ignite?

Comment: I have no idea. Do you have a reproducer for this behavior?